# Unable to get all the values from form's post data in django

Tags: django, forms, post, dictionary, key

I am trying to access the post data from the form , below is my view

```
def retrieve_emails(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print request.POST, ">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>POST"
        if request.POST.has_key('invite'):
            print request.POST['invite'],"------------------> all values"
    return render_to_response('response.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**result**

```
<QueryDict: {u'csrfmiddlewaretoken': [u'GoxxxxxxxxDxxxxxxopg'], u'invite': [u'<steve.b@gmail.com>', u'<kotup@gmail.com>']}> >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>POST

<kotup@gmail.com> ------------------>all values
```

As you can observe from the above result, i can able to get a list of `emails` for the key `invite`  when we print the `request.POST`, but when we try to access/print the key `invite` as in the above code, its printing only one `email` from the `list`

Can anyone please let me know,why is it happening, and why it is returning only one email instead of list of emails ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use [getlist()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.getlist) to get all values, otherwise you can only get the last value. So you need:

```
request.POST.getlist('invite')
```

Hope it helps.